# Nested "For" loop java - how to initialize both variables "i" and "j"?

Tags: java, loops, variables, nested-loops

Let me explain myself:
I have the following loop:

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
for (; i < 6; i++) {
  for (; j < 12 - i; j++) {
    **code**
  }
}
System.out.println(i * j);
```

This is not working well. It does print 72, but it does not print well the circle that I draw inside the loops. I'm trying to draw 72 circle, the first line will have 12 circle, the line underneath 11, and so on.
When I write the code that is above, it only draw the first line of 12 circles and that's it.

I also tried writing "int i=0" and "int j=0" inside the barracks but it did not work because it shows me an error of "the j variable might not have been initialized":

I just want to to draw 6 lines (i is for the lines - first loop) and 12/11/10/9/8/7/6 circles in each line (j is for that - second loop) and also calculate the i*j outside the loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set i and j to zero in the for loop as well, otherwise the j iterators are never reset to zero for each i iteration.

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
         for (i=0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("i  " + i);
            for (j=0; j < 12 - i; j++) {
              System.out.println("j" + j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i * j);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring two variables `i` & `j` before both the loops getting start, but you should initialize those variables into the loops because of the when the values of the variables  increased by loops, it matters.

```
int i,j;
for (i=0; i < 6; i++) {
     for (j=0; j < 12 - i; j++) {
        **code**
     }
  }
  System.out.println(i * j);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `i` and the `j` values within the `for` loop declaration:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 12 - i; j++) {
          **code**
    }
}
System.out.println(i * j);
```

If you initialize a variable within a loop, it can only be seen within that loop. This is called scope. I recommend reading about loop scope for Java.

Comment: Except it doesn't have to do with scope, as you see the result is "seen" outside the loops in with the print statements. It's about resting the counter by redefining `j = 0` with each iteration of `i`

Comment: Note too that I changed your wording from "declare" to "define" since you are declaring it outside the loop but defining it within the loop. Also, "initialize" would only refer to the first time a variable is defined.

Comment: If you declare a variable within a loop it cannot be accessed outside the loop.The result is seen outside the loop because I declared the i and j outside the loop

Comment: correct, if you declare it. If you "initialize" it within the loop but "declare" it outside, it will still be seen outside the loop. Regardless, it's not relevant to the question since the variables were already declared outside the loop.